# Button behind transparent Hbox unclickable

Tags: apache-flex, transparency, containers

I have a HBox with no background, but with some children. Behind the HBox is a button which need to be clicked. The button is unclickable at the moment because the HBox is on top of it. I need the button to be clickable and still have the HBox on top of it.

Is there a way to accomplish this, because I can't seem to find a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hBox.mouseEnabled=false;
hBox.mouseChildren=false;
```

Comment: mouseEnabled=false helped me, had to change a few things on the children but this is a better approach. thanks for your help.